# Will the SHA256Managed Class return different results when run on different machines?

Tags: c#, .net, hash, cryptography

I am attempting to build an authentication mechanism using API keys for access.

As a precaution against relay attacks, I am hashing the API key with the current DateTime and checking on the server side.

Using the same code to hash on both the client and server, I get different results from each of the two calls.

I.E: the Client hashes its API key and sends the hashed key and the datetime "salt" to the server.

The server takes the expected api key and hashed with the datetime sent from the client.

My hashes never match(Client hash != server hash).

This only occurs when I am running the client and server on seperate machines(actually another developer is attempting to write the client portion)

Everything works fine when I test on my local machine(running both client and server portions and attempting the authentication).

**Question**
Given the same input, will the .NET SHA256Managed class ComputeHash method return different results when run on different computers?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Create a random salt (as bytes) and send that to the server instead. I you require text, encode the salt as a hexadecimal string.

Comment: `SHA256Managed` not thread-safe, so it could produce different results if you are calling the same instance from different threads

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Given the same input, will the .NET SHA256Managed class ComputeHash method return different results when run on different computers?

No. If it does than the implementation is broken (unlikely), or the input is different.

Answer (score 1):

Take care if you use `string` because the encoding, current culture... might differ between different computers and that will give you different results (because the **input** is different byte-wise).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. You may have saved us some headaches. Testing some theories now...

Answer (score 1):

The hash should always be the same. Your problem is likely because you are using the string representation of the date as the salt, and the string representation is different on each machine due to locale settings.

Comment: Is the string representation of date time different even within the same timezone/country. I.e both of us are in the eastern us(different states though)

Comment: It doesn't matter where the machines are _physically_ - it only matters where they think they are. Verify the system wide locale.